# How to set an system property in build.sbt, and read it in scala application code?

Tags: scala, sbt, system-properties

I tried to set some system properties in "build.sbt", then read it in my scala application.

In `build.sbt`:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

fork := true

javaOptions := Seq("-Daaa=bbb")
```

Note I set `aaa=bbb`. Following is my scala code:

In `src/main/scala/hello.scala`:

```
object Hello {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    println("hello, world")
    println(System.getProperty("aaa"))
    println("==========")
  }
}
```

Then I run:

```
$ sbt
$ console
$ Hello.main(null)
```

But it prints:

```
hello, world
null
==========
```

You can see it's still `null`. What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$ sbt
$ console
$ Hello.main(null)
```

Use:

```
$ sbt
$ run-main Hello
```